# Wiping my hard disks, how do I pull out and sort all the music/videos/pictures?

Tags: video, music, sort, photo

Looking to raid my hard disks but need all the important stuff out first, have not been very tidy with my file management, is there a program that will scan my computer and pull out all the video, music and pictures? 
Also placing it into some sort of file structure?
I don't mind using multiple programs.
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The media player "Banshee" will find and put all your MUSIC and VIDEO files in folders. Just be sure to set the "Copy files to media folders when importing" checkbox under "Preferences" before importing. The application "Shotwell" will take care of your pictures and copy them into folders as well. Just look for a similar option before importing... I think i says "Copy to folder when importing" or something with that meaning at least.

!!! Be aware that that when Banshee and Shotwell are done importing your media this way, you will end up with TWO copies of every file. One in your old location and one in the new where these programs put it. This means that you have to be sure you have enough room on your disk. 
PS: YOU CAN CHOOSE AN EXTERNAL DISK AS YOUR IMPORT DESTINATION, THAT WAY YOU WILL BE ABLE TO FIND ALL YOUR FILES AND BACKUP AT THE SAME TIME !!!

Comment: This is what I'm looking to do, get everything in one location organised, copy it to external stuff, wipe everything local raid and start again, copy back :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching for file types.

Open the dash and type `search`, and open Search for Files...
Set it to Search Filesystem, and then start searching `*.avi` to find all .avi videos, and `*.mp3` to find all mp3's.
Once a search is complete, you can copy everything to some folder.

The downside to this will be that you will need to find out what file types you have that you want to save, and that you will end up with a folder with everything mashed together (or one folder per file type if you copy to a new folder each time).
To find which file types you have on your machine, I'd suggest looking around.

Sorting your files can afterwards be done using their metadata (depending on how much they have). For you music files, you can use Ex Falso (available in the software center) to create a folder structure.

For you're videos and pictures, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

For pictures and videos you can try shotwell.  Shotwell will let you set an import folder and assist you with organizing them into a folder structure.